# Displaying 7 days of the week in Gridview Header

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I am trying to display the 7 days of the week inside GridView header so my code below works but would like to display the 7 days of the week based on dropdown selection.  I have drop down that has:

```
WeekStart      WeekEnd
2015-11-15    2015-11-21
2015-11-22    2015-11-28
```

and so on.. so if the selection of the drop down is 2015-11-15 then my gridview header should start displayig from 2015-11-15 to 2015-11-21.  Again if the selectoin from the drop down is 2015-11-22 then the gridview header should display starting from the date that is selected: 2015-11-22 and so forth.. my code currently starts displaying today's date but i want to start displaying the header based on the drop down selection

```
 <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlSelectWeek" runat="server" OnSelectedIndexChanged="ddlSelectWeek_SelectedIndexChanged" Width="200px">
                <asp:ListItem Text="2015-11-15" Value="2015-11-15"></asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem Text="2015-11-22" Value="015-11-22"></asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem Text="2015-11-29" Value="2015-11-29"></asp:ListItem>
            </asp:DropDownList>


 protected void ddlSelectWeek_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
      BindGridview();
    }


 protected void BindGridview()
    {
      if (!this.IsPostBack)
      {
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        dt.Columns.AddRange(new DataColumn[8] {
       new DataColumn("Category"),
       new DataColumn("Day1"),
       new DataColumn("Day2"),
       new DataColumn("Day3"),
       new DataColumn("Day4"),
       new DataColumn("Day5"),
       new DataColumn("Day6"),
       new DataColumn("Day7"),
   });
        //add your category
        dt.Rows.Add("Travelling");
        dt.Rows.Add("Food");
        dt.Rows.Add("Air Fare,");
        dt.Rows.Add("Auto Rental");

        gvCategory.DataSource = dt;
        gvCategory.DataBind();
        //for generating datewise coloumn
        for (int i = 1; i < gvCategory.HeaderRow.Cells.Count; i++)
        {
          gvCategory.HeaderRow.Cells[i].Text = DateTime.Now.AddDays(i - 1).ToString("ddd") + " " + DateTime.Now.AddDays(i - 1).ToShortDateString();
        }
      }
    }
```

Comment: Postback on the drop down list change event and rebuild the gridview using the selected date.

Comment: John, i have updated the code per your suggestion..

Comment: You pretty much have it. Just pass the selected drop down value as a paramter to the BindGridview function and then use that value instead of DateTime.Now. Also remove the if (!this.IsPostBack) check.

Comment: John, the question is HOW, i have tried but not being able to successfully re-adjust my code.. thanks

Comment: Ok I will post some code.

Comment: thanks man, i appreciate..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Give this a try.

```
protected void ddlSelectWeek_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    DateTime theDate;
    DateTime.TryParseExact(this.ddlSelectWeek.SelectedValue, "yyyy-MM-dd", CultureInfo.InvarientCulture, DateTimeStyles.None, out theDate);
    BindGridview(theDate);
}

protected void BindGridview(DateTime theDate)
{
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    dt.Columns.AddRange(new DataColumn[8] {
    new DataColumn("Category"),
    new DataColumn("Day1"),
    new DataColumn("Day2"),
    new DataColumn("Day3"),
    new DataColumn("Day4"),
    new DataColumn("Day5"),
    new DataColumn("Day6"),
    new DataColumn("Day7")
    });

    //add your category
    dt.Rows.Add("Travelling");
    dt.Rows.Add("Food");
    dt.Rows.Add("Air Fare,");
    dt.Rows.Add("Auto Rental");

    gvCategory.DataSource = dt;
    gvCategory.DataBind();
    //for generating datewise coloumn
    for (int i = 1; i < gvCategory.HeaderRow.Cells.Count; i++)
    {
        gvCategory.HeaderRow.Cells[i].Text = theDate.AddDays(i - 1).ToString("ddd") + " " + theDate.AddDays(i - 1).ToShortDateString();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks John, when i select the current week: 2015-11-22 i get something like this in the header: Mon 1/1/000   Tue 1/2/0001 Wed 1/3/0001 etc.. but the data for the other week is good

Comment: sorry everything worked fine, it was just typo from my end.  thanks again

Comment: Np glad I could help.